# Using Text boxes instead of a Subform in Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am currently working within Access 2013 and I am building an application resume database. The database has two primary tables [Personal Information] and [Position Applied For], these two tables are currently in a one to many relationship.

The fields within the [Position Applied For] table include:

1. ID PK
2. Personal ID FK
3. Resume Source Internal
4. Personal Reference
5. Job Board
6. Position Applied For
7. Date of Submission
8. Still need to be looked at
9. Not Qualified
   10.No current match

The problem that I am having with this database is within the form. Currently the Position Applied For table is contained within a subform, since it is the many within the relationship. The problem with this is that the user that I am building this database for does not like subforms and prefer textboxes. In order to satisfy this requirement, I would like to have text boxes instead of the subform, with each textbox being linked to one position the person applies for as if they where in there own separate table similar to the Personal Information being on the one side within the relationship. I am only going to show a maximum of 4 positions. Currently I have it within the form and when I display all of the fields they are only linking to the first position that the person applies for.

Also, this is my first post, so if there is anything that I could do differently or explain more please let me know.

Comment: How does the user even know it is a subform? Is this user designing the app or just using it?

Comment: I randomly do updates with user to ensure that everything is suited to the user needs. The user is only using the app.

Comment: You can style the subform so it looks like it part of the parent. I don't understand your client's objection. If you work against the conventions of Access then it will lead to bugs and you will negate the advantages of using Access to begin with. You may as well build it in a more robust platform like .Net.

Comment: Ok, the user really did not have no real objection to the subform, they only thought it was easier to follow if it was in textboxes.  So Access does not allow this capability? and how would I style the subform as if it is part of the parent?

Comment: A subform can make use of text boxes and still be a subform that has the built in linking capability. But look at the properties of the subform, you will see how you can hide the navigation bar, etc. Its been a long time, I don't remember exactly what to call everything.

Comment: Alright, thank you I will do some further researching and look into the properties sheet. Also, do you suggest using vb.net for beginners or using another database language such as mysql?

Comment: vb.net is fine, especially since there will be similarities with VBA, but keep in mind that blogs and samples you will find during research will overwhelmingly be in c#. I would suggest MSSQL over MySql, especially if you are converting an MS Access app since even the free level of Sql Server will certainly more than suit your needs. There is also better built in support to .Net.